# taking "new java.util.Date()" and making it 1 month prior

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using jaspersoft's iReport and I want to turn the `new java.util.Date()` (which is the current date) into 1 month prior from that date. What do I write in the text field expression to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Joda-Time Java API. Call the [`minusMonths`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMonths%28int%29) method on a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

The jrxml file sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="joda_sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <import value="org.joda.time.DateTime"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="109" y="23" width="175" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Current date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="336" y="23" width="200" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Current date minus one month: " + DateTime.now().minusMonths(1).toString("dd.MM.yyyy")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The result in iReport]

***Note:***
Don't forget to add Joda-Time library to classpath (in my case I've add library to the *iReport*'s classpath).

Comment: Got the result I was looking for! The only (small) issue is that it casts as 05.05.2012 instead of 05/05/2012 which I would prefer.

Comment: @precose It is enough to add only **joda-time-2.1.jar**. Did you restart JR Server?

Comment: You can use any pattern you want.

Comment: Ahh yes, I'm stupid. The question is 100% resolved. Thank you (and the other 2 who tried helping) for everything! It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The Java Date API is notoriously clumsy, there is a useful third party alternative. Try importing http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ library.

See this post:
[Adding a number of days to a JodaTime Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058743/adding-a-number-of-days-to-a-jodatime-instant)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, in the following way:

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(myDate); //Yes, it is strange!!! But we don't really need this, for the getInstance() results in a current date.
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

I realized after your comment that I can't change it into a single expression, for add returns void and not the new Date(). Sorry about that...

Comment: It accepted the string without error but it's coming up as 'null' instead of '05/05/2012'

Comment: Sorry - haven't seen that add returns void, not the altered date. Please ignore my expression.